# Attracting atmospheric positive ions to carbon nano tubes for collection

Tags: magnetic-fields, renewable-energy

Can nano magnets built into carbon nano tubes be used to attract moving positive ions from atmosphere to increase the resultant positively charged collecting mass?

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic fields only *deflect* ions and only if the ions are moving through the magnetic field. You'd need something different or more complex to *attract* ions.

Also your "resultant positively charged collecting mass" would repel the positive ions you are trying to collect.

Comment: If the +ion is moving and it creates its own magnetic field can't the field align attractively with the nanocarbon magnetic fields, statistically speaking. half of the time if the mag fields align and repel or be deflected the rest of the time? Assumming we can control the NanoCarbon Magnetic field alignments consistently to some maximum attraction geometry.